# How to solve jsx-no-bind error on a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a small component to change language of my site. Since the eslint configured with `jsx-no-bind`, it raise error on the bellow code.

```
const ChangeLanguage = ({ toggleLanguage }) => {

    const toggle = () => {
        console.log('hi')
        toggleLanguage()
    }

    return (
        <IconButton
            onClick={toggle}
        >
            <Language /> // this is an svg-icon
        </IconButton>
    )
}

export default connect(null, { toggleLanguage })(ChangeLanguage)
```

I googled the `jsx-no-bind` usage. Somebody said we should enable it since in every render javascript generates new function and it caused an unnecessary render(like airbnb code convention[[link]](http://airbnb.io/javascript/react/)). But some others said its performance improvement is negligible and it decrease readability of code (like this [[link]](http://shzhangji.com/blog/2018/09/13/is-it-necessary-to-apply-eslint-jsx-no-bind-rule)). Here is two question:

1. How to solve the error(i.e without disabling `jsx-no-bind`).
2. What is your suggestion about `jsx-no-bind` configuration(i.e I should remove it completely/partially from eslint configuration or not?).

**PS:** There are more documentation about passing arrow function or binding methods as props in the web. But I mentioned just two of them in the question statement.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is documented here: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#react-hooks

> Functional components are often used alongside hooks, and the most trivial case would occur if your callback is completely independent from your state. In this case, the solution is as simple as moving the callback out of your component:

```
const onClick = () => {
  console.log("Independent callback");
};
const Button = () => {
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Label</button>
  );
};
```

> Otherwise, the idiomatic way to avoid redefining callbacks on every render would be to memoize them using the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook:

```
const Button = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Before click");
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    setText("After click");
  }, [setText]); // Array of dependencies for which the memoization should update
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

eslint doesn't complain if we do:

```
const ChangeLanguage = ({ toggleLanguage }) => {

    function toggle () {
        console.log('hi')
        toggleLanguage()
    }

    return (
        <IconButton
            onClick={toggle}
        >
            <Language /> // this is an svg-icon
        </IconButton>
    )
}

export default connect(null, { toggleLanguage })(ChangeLanguage)
```

But I'm not sure what the difference is. Is react in this case not creating a function on each render anymore, or just rule don't recognise it?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you passed a function in the return statement of your component, and that creates a new function every time the component re renders.

to avoid that, you can only use it's reference instead. like this,

```
const ChangeLanguage = ({ toggleLanguage }) => {
return (
    <IconButton
        onClick={toggleLanguage} // <----->
        <Language /> // this is an svg-icon
    </IconButton>
 )
}
```

`export default connect(null, { toggleLanguage })(ChangeLanguage)`

Comment: You are right. The problem here solved but what we can do if we must pass a function as props(in other situations)... How can pass a func as onClick props without error(i.e unnecessary render side-effect)

Comment: well, I personally didn't face a situation where you "must" create a function in the return statement, you could define the function outside the return or the render method and pass it's reference inside. 

OR if all hope is lost, you can simply disable the eslint rule for this file by writing a comment

like: 
same line : // eslint-disable-line jsx-no-bind
next line : // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-no-bind
all code underneath: /* eslint-disable jsx-no-bind */

Comment: I change the code a little without changing the original problem. Suppose we must/want to do something else as well (like printing an string to console)... . The problem still is there!

Comment: I believe because that's still inside the render since it's a functional component, if you switch it up to a class based component you can define the function outside of the render method and and it would work.

I'm not sure if `useCallback()` hook bypass this rule or not, suggest you try/look it up.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about `useCallback` hook, I will look at it. But for the first part, (since its better to define funcational component instead of class based) now the Q is its better to define a class which obey `jsx-no-bind` rule or a functional component which do not?!

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Ignore this linter rule. Functional components are just function, a children function will be executed every time the parent is executed.

#### Long story

If you're reading this at 2023, this rule is not valid anymore, it was made mostly for class components. On functional components your component will be re-rendered regardless the function type (regular, arrow, anonymous, named, inline or extracted to a variable), if the parent state changes then a whole re-render of that part of the tree will be executed. If you want to avoid that you have to use `useCallback` + `memo`.

You can play with my example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dhx8aq?file=App.tsx